# Proof of the no-communication theorem

Tags: measurement, density-matrix, communication

Let $A, B$ be (finite-dimensional) Hilbert spaces, and $\rho$ some mixed state of $A \otimes B$. I am trying to show that a measurement performed on the '$A$-subsystem' does not affect $\rho^B = \text{Tr}_A(\rho)$.

I understand a 'measurement performed on the $A$-subsystem' as given by some observable $X \otimes I$, where $X$ is a self-adjoint operator on $A$ which decomposes as $X = \sum m P_m$ (where $P_m$ is the orthogonal projection on the $m$-eigenspace). If this measurement results in outcome $m$, the resulting state should be

$$\rho' = \frac{(P_m \otimes I) \rho (P_m \otimes I)}{\text{Tr}((P_m \otimes I) \rho)}$$
and I wish to see that $\text{Tr}_A(\rho') = \text{Tr}_A(\rho)$. Now I can use the cyclicity of trace to see that

$$\text{Tr}_A(\rho') = \frac{\text{Tr}_A((P_m \otimes I) \rho)}{\text{Tr}((P_m \otimes I) \rho)}$$

but why should this be equal to $\text{Tr}_A(\rho)$? I did check this is the case if $\rho = \rho^A \otimes \rho^B$ decomposes as a product. And I know a general $\rho$ will be a linear combination of such cases; but since the equality desired is not linear, it does not seem to follow that it'll hold (in fact, it seems to indicate it will *not* hold). Hopefully someone can point to the mistake in my thinking.

Comment: One way would be to compare the expectation value of an arbitrary local operator $M_A$ on $\rho_A$ with that of the global one $M_A \otimes I_B$ and $\rho_{AB}$, see for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace#Partial_trace_as_a_quantum_operation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've denoted as $\rho'$ is just an $m$-th possible outcome. We have to write
$$
\rho'_m = \frac{(P_m \otimes I) \rho (P_m \otimes I)}{\text{Tr}((P_m \otimes I) \rho)}.
$$
Now, since Bob doesn't know the value of $m$ he has to assume that the new state is a mixture of $\rho'_m$ with corresponding probabilities $\text{Tr}((P_m \otimes I) \rho)$. So, the actual $\rho'$ is
$$
\rho' = \sum_m \rho'_m \text{Tr}((P_m \otimes I) \rho) = \sum_m (P_m \otimes I) \rho (P_m \otimes I).
$$
Finally, you can see that
$$
\text{Tr}_A(\rho') = 
\sum_m \text{Tr}_A((P_m \otimes I) \rho (P_m \otimes I)) = 
$$
$$
= \sum_m \text{Tr}_A(\rho (P_m \otimes I)) = 
\text{Tr}_A(\rho \sum_m (P_m \otimes I)) = \text{Tr}_A(\rho).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this equation does not hold. Take for example $\rho = |\phi^+\rangle\langle \phi^+|$, where $|\phi^+\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$. If Alice obtains outcome 0, then $\rho' = |00\rangle\langle 00|$, and $\rho^B = |0\rangle\langle0|$, and if Alice obtains outcome 1, then $\rho' = |11\rangle\langle 11|$, and $\rho^B = |1\rangle\langle1|$. This is the typical example of the nonlocality of wavefunction collapse.

The statement of the no-communication theorem is that when you *average* over Alice's outcomes, then the result does not depend on which measurement she made, or indeed if she made a measurement at all. Let then
$$\rho_m = \frac{(P_m \otimes I) \rho (P_m \otimes I)}{\text{Tr}((P_m \otimes I) \rho)},$$
the collapsed state after obtaining measurement result $m$, and
$$\rho^B_m = \operatorname{tr}_A (\rho_m).$$
The theorem is then that $$\sum_m p(m) \rho^B_m = \rho^B = \operatorname{tr}_A\rho,$$
for all possible projectors $P_m$, or even POVM elements.